# Using models in Play Framework for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I have some Play Framework models looking similar to:

```
class BookieRepo @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) {
  val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]
  val db = dbConfig.db
  import dbConfig.profile.api._

  def all: Future[Seq[BookiesRow]] =
    db.run(Bookies.result)
}
```

My web application runs fine and is able to use these models. However I need to invoke some 'standalone' part of my app to gather the data from websites and put it into DB.
What's the recommended way to acquire access to these model's methods in my objects extending App and being started by crontab?
Is StaticApplication what I need here? Doesn't it mean that I would have 2 apps (the standard one and the static one) running concurrently then?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like in previous versions of Play Framework this was possible through GlobalSettings.

If you are using version 2.6.x, they suggest putting the code you need to run on start-up in the constructor a dependency injected class.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/GlobalSettings

If you are on a version of Play Framework before 2.6.x, you should still be able to do it, by looking at 
https://playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaGlobal

Good luck!

Comment: Ok so because I need to invoke some actions periodically it seems for me that I need to put in crontab some http invocation via curl or wget and use HttpRequestHandler in Scala code. Is that right?

Comment: It seems that there is no need to use HttpRequestHandler at all but invoke appropriate action in some Controller after invoking this controller by a http request from crontab. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Ok so to get this straight, you need to perform some operation (getting data from somewhere and inserting into database) on startup as well as periodically? Also, be careful with your wording using the word "action." It's a bit confusing to follow because of Play Actions (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActions) as I'm sure you're aware of

Comment: You are right - I have used the word action in an incorrect way. I need to get the data and insert it only periodically, not on startup.

Comment: Ok, I don't know about all the details about your application so it's hard to suggest the "best" plan of action. If you are already using crontab, then maybe it's a decent solution, but I believe that would mean you're exposing your API in ways you may not want to. To keep it private, you could use Akka scheduler https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/guide/introduction.html which will allow you to essentially do a setInterval( ) which performs some operation after a given amount of time repeatedly until you cancel it.